# Sound lag/glitch while browsing internet (loading pages)

Tags: windows, windows-8, audio, internet, browser

yeah that's crazy. Never happened this before, but started happening few days ago and can't trace down what. And please don't suggest audio drivers, it worked fine for ages and I got latest version. Also this issue gets fixed when restarting PC and starts happening only after like PC was on and used for like 3-4 hours.

So what happens is that while playing music or watching a movie and at the same time browsing the internet, i.e. loading pages, sound starts glitching and CPU jumps, it obviously gives sign that for some reason something running slow. The thing is the PC is new i3 with 8GB of RAM on Win8 x64.

I tried running various programs at the same time launching Photoshop and other stuff on 100% CPU to see if glitch appears and nothing. Also copying files at 100% HDD use and still no glitch. But if I go to browser internet and load a page it starts glitching and CPU jumping up to 100% for like second or so until page loads. Also tried IE, Firefox, Chrome and Opera - same glitching.

I did scan for viruses using Avast, Kaspersky, I have Agnitum firewall and Spybot Search & Destroy for malware. I didn't find anything.

Like I said this never happened before, just now out of nowhere and I didn't do anything. And I don't have any system restore points left.

There's a Google link to similar problem I found (top link) http://goo.gl/YwyPWB (but updating audio drivers dont help).

I know that's crazy.

Comment: Do you get the same issue while [starting Windows in safe mode with networking](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)? Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) already?

Comment: But like I said it takes like 3-4 hours till issue starts happening, I can't wait that long on Safe Mode for the issue to come up also afaik safe mode don't load sound.

Comment: Sound is disabled by default in safe mode, but it can be enabled eventually. If you can't wait that long, perform a clean boot. That should help you determine whether third party software is involved.

Comment: But that will disable protection services like antivirus and firewall and I didnt install anything for months, same old software and being using this PC every day. And like I said this happens while surfing with any browser and while at loading pages. And no new services or anything was done and strangest thing is that this happens only after hours using the PC since start.

Comment: You could also boot a different operating system (e.g. any Linux live distribution) to check if the issue is caused by software or hardware malfunction.

Comment: I reinstalled all drivers I had, also updated BIOS and etc. I will let you know if this solved anything.

Comment: Lol just noticed the issue appearing again. Glitching while loading pages. Drive me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to uninstall Agnitum Outpost Firewall. Solved.

Comment: Did you uninstall this from the control panel or from the browser?